¿Cómo enviar el contenido de un <textarea>?
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde necesito enviar el contenido de un textarea en mi página web a una dirección de Gmail. No estoy segura de cómo proceder para que, al hacer clic en un botón, el contenido del textarea se envíe automáticamente como cuerpo de un correo electrónico.
He intentado algunas cosas, pero no he tenido éxito. A continuación, comparto parte de mi código:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
   <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
   <title>Sugerencias</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
   <div class="formulario4">
   <br>
   <center>
    <div class="colort">
       <h1>Envía tus Sugerencias</h1>
       <p>Nos encantaría saber tus ideas y comentarios.</p>
    </div>
       <div class="container">
           <form action="https://formsubmit.co/yyy@gmail.com" method="POST">
               <textarea name = "coments" class="styled-textarea" placeholder="Escribe algo aquí..." required></textarea>
               <div class="buttons">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
                   <button type="reset" class="btn cancel">Cancelar</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="">
               </div>
           </form>
           <br>
       </div>
   </center>
   <?php
$paracorreo ="xxx@gmail.com";
$titulo ="test correo";
$mensaje="por favor";
$tucorreo="From: yyy@gmail.com";

if(mail($paracorreo,$titulo,$mensaje,$tucorreo))
{
    echo "correo enviado";
}else{
    echo "error";
}
?>

</div>
<?php 
include("footerphp");

?>
</body>
</html>

Disculpen si no se preguntar

Tal como lo tienes no conseguirás hacerlo, esta claro, pero además, me pregunto desde donde estás intentando enviar ese email, porque si lo quieres mandar a gmail, es probable que no llegue nunca aunque el script sea correcto, porque gmail y otros rechazan correos que no cumplen con las autenticaciones correctas de SPF/DKIM/DMARC del dominio que lo manda. Es decir, que te puede ser muy dificil saber si el correo ha salido o no, pues dudo que te llegue ningun mensaje de error en ninguna parte al enviarlo pues segun parece pretendes mandalo como si fuera de gmail.com y no lo conseguiras así.

lo estoy intentando mandar desde una pagina web que hice mediante visual code, tienes razon en lo demas, gracias lo tomare en cuenta <3

Si la página web que dices la tienes alojada en un dominio, entonces cambia el $tucorreo poniendo un email de ese dominio en lugar del yyy@gmail.com, a ver si así solucionas el problema del SPF/DKIM/DMARC (eso si ese dominio los tiene bien puestos).  Por otra parte, ahora veo que usas formsubmit.co para enviar el correo, así que teoricamente te sobra todo lo del mail() y simplemente debes modificar tu formulario para que se parezca a lo que ellos te muestran aquí: https://formsubmit.co/live-demo
